GoogleChromeの拡張機能Tampermonkey(UserScriipt)を使用して、ダウンロードファイル名を希望のものにしたい。
GoogleChromeの拡張機能Tampermonkey(UserScriipt)を使用して、ダウンロードファイル名を希望のものにしたい。
現在は、
ページ内にダウンロードボタンがあり、押すとjavascriptが走り、サーバーサイドではPHPが走って、CSVファイルが生成される。そして、Windowsの名前をつけて保存ダイアログが表示される。
希望は、
この「Windowsの名前をつけて保存ダイアログ」にデフォルト表示されているファイル名を、Tampermonkeyから使用して指定したい。（その時表示中のページ（特定の1つのページを想定している）のチェックボックスやリストボックスの値から、ファイル名を指定したいので。）
試してみたこと
var downloadElement = document.getElementsByName('btn_csv'); // download_ボタンID
if(downloadElement[0]) {
    downloadElement[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var csv_filename = ''+school_year+"年度"+grade_txt+testkindcd_txt

        if (document.forms[0].OUTPUT_PATERN.value == "4") {
            csv_filename=csv_filename+"4"
        }else if(document.forms[0].OUTPUT_PATERN.value == "5") {
            csv_filename=csv_filename+"5"
        }else{
        }
        csv_filename = csv_filename + '.CSV';
        if(csv_filename) {
            downloadElement.setAttribute('download', csv_filename); 
        }
    });
}

サーバーサイドは変更することはできません。
サーバーサイドでファイル名が指定されているようで、そのフィル名になってしまいます。
それを上書きして、自分で指定したいです。
そもそも、tampermonkeyでデフォルトファイル名を上書きすることはできないのでしょうか？
できるなら、そのやり方をご教授ください。
追記

ダウンロード動作直接では出来ないのなら、ダウンロードが完了してから名前を変える間接的な方法にすれば良いのでは？ あと本質ではないですが、差し支えなければサーバーが規定する完全なファイル名とそれを変更してどのような名前にしたいかの具体的な例(何故そうした操作/選択をやりたいのかも含めて)がいくつかあると良いかもしれません。

ダウンロード時には指定出来ないのなら、ダウンロードが完了したら直ちに名前を変えるという方法はtampermonkeyで可能でしょうか。この場合はどのように書けばよいですか？
サーバーが規定するファイル名が「令和6年成績.csv」であるところを、「令和6年_1年_中間成績.csv」「令和6年_3年_期末成績.csv」のような感じのファイル名にしたい。サーバーが規定するファイル名は、いつも同じでそのCSVファイルの内容を表していない。出力したCSVは、のちにエクセルから使うのでわかりやすい名前を付けておきたい。毎回手入力は大変なので、ダウンロードファイル名をその時表示中のページのリストボックスの値からtampermonkeyで指定したい。
余談
学校の成績処理システムが外注のもので、本来なら依頼して修正してもらえば一番よいのですが時間とお金の点で、中々修正はされない。仕方ないので、tampermonkeyでカバーしようかな、という趣旨です。

btn_csv 要素はどんなHTMLですか? (タグ名、付いている属性など)

ダウンロード動作直接では出来ないのなら、ダウンロードが完了してから名前を変える間接的な方法にすれば良いのでは？ あと本質ではないですが、差し支えなければサーバーが規定する完全なファイル名とそれを変更してどのような名前にしたいかの具体的な例(何故そうした操作/選択をやりたいのかも含めて)がいくつかあると良いかもしれません。

ちなみにこんな記事が参考になるかも。Chrome Extensionを作ってみよう, onDeterminingFilenameと利用上の注意 - (｡ゝω･)ﾉ*:ﾟ･ - FC2, Chrom Extension: onDeterminingFilenme interfers with all downloads

その後こんな記事も。ファイルダウンロードできるChrome拡張(Chrome Extension)をつくる なお、一つ前のコメントも含めて tampermonkey との関係や使えるかどうかは不明です。

ダウンロードが完了したら直ちに名前を変えるというアイデアは単なる思い付きですので、解説の付いている WebSurfer さんの回答の方が使えそうです。それと被っていそうですが一応こんな記事のタイミングなり方法が参考になるかもしれません。JavaScriptでダウンロード完了を検知する5つの方法 tampermonkey で使えるかどうかは同じく不明ですが。


GoogleChromeの拡張機能Tampermonkey(UserScriipt)を使用して、ダウンロードファイル名を希望のものにしたい。

「Tampermonkey(UserScriipt)を使用して」という要望に対する直接の答えではありませんが、クライアントスクリプト（XMLHttpRequest とか fetch API）を使ってダウンロードすれば、その際ファイル名を指定できますので、その方法を紹介します。
ダウンロードしたファイルを Blob（生データ）として取得し、それを保存するためのスクリプトを書きますが、その際ファイル名を指定できます。
保存するためのスクリプトは、URL API をサポートしてない IE, 旧 Edge の場合は msSaveBlob method を使います。ファイル名は msSaveBlob の第 2 引数に設定します。
URL API をサポートしているブラウザの場合は URL.createObjectURL を使って Blob の URL を取得し、それを html の a 要素の href 属性に設定し、download 属性にファイル名を設定してスクリプトでクリックするようにします。
具体例は以下のコードを見てください。
XMLHttpRequest を利用
function download() {
  var url = "/Home/FileDownload";
  var filename = "testfile";
 
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var blob = this.response;
 
      //IE, 旧 Edge とその他で処理の切り分け
      if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename + ".pdf");
      } else {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        // IE11, 旧 Edge  は URL API をサポートしてない
        var url = window.URL;
        a.href = url.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob],
                                     { type: blob.type }));
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";
        a.download = filename + ".pdf";
        a.click();
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}

jQuery Ajax を利用
jQuery バージョン 3.0 以降であれば Blob を取得できます。以下の例では IE11, 旧 Edge の場合の処理は省略しています。
const jqueryAjax = () => {
    const url = "/Download/VirtualFileResult";
    const filename = "testjquery";
 
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        xhrFields: { responseType: "blob" }
    }).done(blob => {
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        const url = window.URL;
        a.href = url.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob],
            { type: blob.type }));
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";
        a.download = filename + ".pdf";
        a.click();
    }).fail((jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
        // エラー処理（省略）
    });
};

fetch API を利用
fetch 関数の戻り値の Response オブジェクトの blob メソッドで blob を取得できます。async / await と組み合わせることにより、上の 2 つの例より、可読性がかなり向上すると思います。
const fetchApi = async () => {
    const url = "/Download/VirtualFileResult";
    const filename = "testfetch";
 
    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (response.ok) {
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        const url = window.URL;
        a.href = url.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob],
            { type: blob.type }));
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";
        a.download = filename + ".pdf";
        a.click();
    } else {
        // エラー処理（省略）
    }
};


回答ありがとうございます。Tampermonkeyを使用して解決したいと考えています。

Blob、fetch APIなど私の知らない技術があって、少し理解に時間がかかりそうです。ゆっくり読ませていただきます。丁寧なご回答ありがとうございました。
